# Redux doesn't fetch data from API request

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React/Redux. I'm making an app using an API but the code doesn't work. When I run the code it says "this.props.recipes.map is not a function" and doesn't render anything.

If I change payload to: "payload: response.data.recipes" then the error changes to "Given action "FETCH_RECIPE", reducer "recipes" returned undefined." but no errors on screen (only in console). I thought writing "(state = [], action)" would solve the problem but it seems not. What's the problem and how do I fix this error?

```
Action Creator

import recipe from '../apis/recipe';

export const fetchRecipe = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await recipe.get('');

    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_RECIPE', payload: response.data })
};
```

```
Reducer

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const recipeReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_RECIPE':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default combineReducers({
    recipes: recipeReducer
});
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchRecipe } from '../actions';

class Recipe extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchRecipe();
        console.log("This doesn't work", this.props.recipes)
    }

    renderList() {
        return this.props.recipes.map(recipe => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>{recipe.publisher}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        console.log("First loaded: empty, second time: data fetched", this.props.recipes)
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderList()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { recipes: state.recipes }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{
    fetchRecipe
})(Recipe);
```

```
API Request

import axios from 'axios';
import { key } from './config';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${key}&q=pizza`
});
```

Comment: Can you show what is the underlying code of this method? await recipe.get('');

Comment: Simply means that when your app first loads, the `reducer` state is empty which throws an error. You could simply do this by setting an initial empty state, until the API completes and gets you the data

Comment: @keysl await recipe.get(''); is referring to "import recipe from '../apis/recipe';" The code is the very last one.

Comment: @Panther I put "state = [],". Is that what you mean?

Comment: `map is not a function` clearly states that `props.recipes` is not an array. First check it if its any array. Secondly on changing the payload, you need to send an array to the reducer, since you have the response payload, determine what needs to get stored and send it appropriately to the reducer.

Comment: @Panther Thanks! I don't exactly remember how I got it to there but it worked!